# How do I get a camera to rotate instead of rotating the object in viewport

Tags: camera

New to blender coming from c4d. I need to set a camera to rotate around the object and at any time I would like to render the image or even to press 0 on my numpad the image it's exactly the one I have in my viewport. How do I do this in blender?

Comment: to rotate around the object is a bit too vague, do you need your camera to follow a circle shape around the object, do you need an animation, etc? Please give some details

Answer (score 1):

You can set the behavior of the viewport to 'Orbit around Selected' in Edit > Preferences > Navigation.

You can center on selected in the viewport by hitting <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>.

You can make the active camera adopt the viewport view by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

These could add up to the sort of interacion you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different ways to do this but I prefer the following method.

Add an empty at the center of your target object.

Set up your camera at the desired distance from the object.

Parent your camera to empty by selecting the camera first then shift-selecting the empty.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> create the parent relationship.

Now anything you do to the empty, will by inheritance also happen to the camera.

Now you can simply rotate the empty (you can also animate this easily) and your camera will maintain the distance at which it was parented making it orbit.

The easiest way to animate this is to double click the Z rotation of the empty and enter:

`#frame/31.415926535`

This will create a driver that rotates the empty at a rate of 1 revolution  per 200 frames.  You can tweak this after, but you only need to use the `#` symbol the first time to tell blender that you want to use a driver.